# JBoss isn't reachable, why?

Tags: port, jboss

I'm running CentOS 6 (for 32-bit architectures) on a 20GB partition of my laptop. I'm trying to install JBoss 7.1.1 with java 8 (`JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152`). Basically I followed this online [guide](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/09/11/how-to-install-jboss-application-server-in-centos-6-x/) but now when I start Jboss as management user "jboss", I can't reach the server through Firefox ("Unable to connect"). Yet I know the server is running, the CPU is working at max speed and `ps -ef | grep jboss` yields lots of output. When I try to stop the server I get

```
[jboss@centos jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller
at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:22
[...output truncated...]
```

I suspected `iptables` for blocking the traffic so I set rules for ports 8080 and 9990:

```
[dolly@centos opt]$ sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:631 
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:631 
7    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:631 
8    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         state NEW udp dpt:5353 
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8080 
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9990 
13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8080 /* Jboss AppSrv */ 
14   REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
[dolly@centos opt]$ sudo service iptables save
```

Can't `telnet localhost 8080` but can `ping localhost`. 
Here's `netstat`:

```
[dolly@centos jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ netstat -napt | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58074               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::57773                    :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
[dolly@centos jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$
```

Still can't connect via browser to the Application Server. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: To stop the server I have to use `kill -9 PID` because the shutdown command above isn't working. So how do I find out why is it saying "_Failed to connect to the controller_"? Where do I start inquiring?

Comment: What say the jboss log?

Comment: Nothing relevant in `boot.log`; no other log files are being created.

Comment: Seems your server doesn’t start correctly if not is present server.log